# unable to find a register to spill in class 'POINTER_REGS' (maybe compiler bug)

Tags: c++, avr-gcc, compiler-bug

The issue is that this code will not compile with avr-g++ compiler. It produces the error in the headline. When you comment out either line 15 or 16, it will compile. If you remove ''colourArray'' or ''blackArray'' from the right side of line 15 and 16, it will compile. And if you replace ''greyDiff'' in line 15 and 16 with the respective right sides of the variable assignments. It does compile if it is not in the for loop. Isn't that a compiler bug?

```
float colourArrayL[3] = {0, 0, 0};
float whiteArrayL[3] = {0, 0, 0};
float blackArrayL[3] = {0, 0, 0};
float colourArrayR[3] = {0, 0, 0};
float whiteArrayR[3] = {0, 0, 0};
float blackArrayR[3] = {0, 0, 0};

void setup()
{
  for (byte i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  {
    float greyDiffL = whiteArrayL[i] - blackArrayL[i]; //the highest possible return minus the lowest returns the area for values in between
    float greyDiffR = whiteArrayR[i] - blackArrayR[i];

    colourArrayL[i] = (colourArrayL[i] - blackArrayL[i]) / greyDiffL;
    colourArrayR[i] = (colourArrayR[i] - blackArrayR[i]) / greyDiffR;
  }
}

void loop() {};
```

Comment: what compiler version?

Comment: See also [Arduino issue 3972](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/3972), [GCC 60040](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60040), [Stackoverflow question 39255127](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255127/arduino-error-unable-to-find-a-register-to-spill-in-class-no-regs)

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with avr-g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 and had a similar experience when writing a copy constructor for a custom class rgbscenario00. The error showed when copying more than 5 rgbled objects inside the copy constructor. I solved this by adding 2 private methods (using divide & conquer). So it seems the compiler tries to use all registers, and when they have all been used, it just stops with an error. Here is my solution (showing only the significant part:)

```
void rgbscenario00::copyrgb123( const rgbscenario00& orig ) {
    magenta         = orig.magenta;
    rood            = orig.rood;
    geel            = orig.geel;
}   

void rgbscenario00::copyrgb456( const rgbscenario00& orig ) {
    groen           = orig.groen;
    blauw           = orig.blauw;
    oranje          = orig.oranje; 
    // uncommenting this last oranje line resulted in
    // "error: unable to find a register to spill 
    // in class 'POINTER_REGS'  "
}

rgbscenario00::rgbscenario00(const rgbscenario00& orig) {
    // I have to split up this copy constructor to avoid 
    // getting a very silly error on the lack of registers
    copyrgb123( orig );
    copyrgb456( orig );
    //magenta = orig.magenta; rood  = orig.rood;  geel = orig.geel;
    //groen   = orig.groen;   blauw = orig.blauw;
    //oranje  = orig.oranje; 
    // uncommenting this oranje line resulted in  
    // "error: unable to find a register to spill 
    // in class 'POINTER_REGS'  "
    inputString         = orig.inputString;
    stringComplete      = orig.stringComplete;
    iteller             = orig.iteller;
    huedeviation        = orig.huedeviation;
    lumdeviation        = orig.lumdeviation;
    uiteller            = orig.uiteller;
    ujchosen            = orig.ujchosen;
    usbspeed            = orig.usbspeed;
    currentmillis       = orig.currentmillis;
    prevmillis          = orig.prevmillis;
    millisperloop       = orig.millisperloop;
    millisperstep       = orig.millisperstep;
    tfuture             = orig.tfuture;
    tstep               = orig.tstep;
    copyboolarray(&(computed[0]),&(orig.computed[0]),maxuirgblednum );
    copyboolarray(&(done[0]),    &(orig.done[0]),    maxuirgblednum );  
    copyuliarray( &(nexttime[0]),&(orig.nexttime[0]),maxuirgblednum );
    copyuiarray(&(uilumvalues[0]),&(orig.uilumvalues[0]),
                maxuilumvalues );
}
```